# Add Script tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I've included a script in jQuery, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you take a look at the code and enlighten me?

```
<div id="foo"></div>

$('#foo').append('<script> some code </script>');
```

Comment: **Please** format this code better. Putting each statement onto separate lines will show a good faith effort on your part and make it easier for others to read your code and answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you are using javascript to insert some javascript, why not just run the javascript snippet:

```
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

Where you have:

```
$('#foo').append(...);
```

Just insert that code from Twitter. It will do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I would strip your script out off the page into its own nice clean file and then pull it in via jquery

```
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
$("#someElement").append( script );
```

Comment: @Dominic Green how can we pass variable within the append tag
for eg in the above example:
$("#someElement").append(script(q));
can we do it??

Comment: Its not a function so you cant pass in a variable. However if you declare a variable above the append your code should be able to access it