# Error in loading html dynamically through jquery having one script

Tags: jquery, html

I have write a code for loading html dynamically through jQuery

```
$("table").eq(5).html('<table><tr><td>some data</td></tr></table><script language="JavaScript">function TCN_reload(from){}</script><table><tr><td>some data</td></tr></table>');
```

If I use this code then page load error has encountered.
but if I remove that Script then there is no error but I want that script too.

Please help me out!

Thank you!

Comment: Yo - you are setting table inside table?

Comment: what are you trying to ... ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Script tag in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538146/add-script-tag-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<script language="javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript">`. Check the detailed explanation below

`type = content-type :`

```
This attribute specifies the scripting language of the elements contents and overrides the default scripting language. The scripting language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/javascript" ). We have to supply a value for this attribute. There is no default value for this attribute.
```

`language ="JavaScript" :`

```
This attribute specifies the scripting language of the contents of this element. Its value is an identifier for the language, but since these identifiers are not standard, this attribute has been deprecated(outdated by newer constructs) in favor of type.
```

Comment: Switching from HTML 3.2 to HTML 4.x won't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for dynamically inserting javascript inside dom element. remove the javascript .it will work

to add javascript you can follow this

[put javascript into jquery .html function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693959/put-javascript-into-jquery-html-function)